# I can't install the accelerate package because it requires an older version of base

Tags: haskell, installation, package, gpu

I want to install accelerate 1.3 (at time the latest version of a gpu acceleration package), either using stack or cabal (preferably cabal). It requires an older version of base than I have... how do I switch GHC versions locally so that when I do `cabal run`, I can use accelerate, but keep using the latest GHC version for my other projects?

The version of base required for accelerate is 4.12 <= version < 4.15. I have base 4.18 on my current GHC version.

```
Error: cabal-3.10.2.1.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: gpu-acceleration-haskell-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of gpu-acceleration-haskell)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.17.2.1/installed-4.17.2.1 (conflict:
gpu-acceleration-haskell => base^>=4.12)
[__1] skipping: base-4.19.0.0, base-4.18.2.0, base-4.18.1.0, base-4.18.0.0,
base-4.17.2.1, base-4.17.2.0, base-4.17.1.0, base-4.17.0.0, base-4.16.4.0,
base-4.16.3.0, base-4.16.2.0, base-4.16.1.0, base-4.16.0.0, base-4.15.1.0,
base-4.15.0.0, base-4.14.3.0, base-4.14.2.0, base-4.14.1.0, base-4.14.0.0,
base-4.13.0.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the previous version
to fail: excluded by constraint '^>=4.12' from 'gpu-acceleration-haskell')
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0,
base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0,
base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1,
base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0,
base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0,
base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, gpu-acceleration-haskell)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, gpu-acceleration-haskell
```

Comment: How did you install GHC?

Comment: @ollimandoliini I installed using `ghcup`

Comment: You should also consider installing [accelerate from source](https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate/), it looks like the repo has been updated since but not pushed to Hackage yet.

Comment: What is `gpu-acceleration-haskell`? What happens if you pass `--allow-newer=base` to cabal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably knew already, `base` versions are directly linked to certain GHC versions. You can see the versions [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package).

To change a GHC version with GHCUp, run `ghcup tui`, *install* the version you want to use and then *set* it as the active version.

Another option is to install the correct version with GHCUp and specify the GHC version in your "cabal.project" file using the `with-compiler` property, e.g. `with-compiler: ghc-8.10.7`.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that "setting" the ghc version in ghcup would affect all projects?

Comment: That’s correct.